# Using Key signature but scale is going out onto ledger lines

Tags: scales, key-signatures, accidentals, clefs

I am working through my grade 1 theory book and am a little confused on a question. I have learnt that you either use key signatures or accidentals when writing out a scale. Not both.

The question I have is asking me to write a descending F major scale on the bass clef but the B flat note is on a ledger line. Do I put an accidental in front of it or not?[image]

Thanks

Comment: As soon as you get into harmonic and melodic minors, you *have* to use *both* key sig and accidentals! Sorry!

Comment: Not sure that would be marked correct. Once a key sig is stated, there's no need to write in the accidental for the affected note/s. They're already flattened. At grade I it'll probably be allowed, but please check with teacher. Your 1st para. alludes to that.

Comment: In all the theory methods I have done in the last four years both British and South African none would want you to repeat the key signature like that.

Comment: You can be glad I'm not your teacher otherwise I'd make you write than again (-;

Comment: @NeilMeyer - by 'initial' do you mean 'write an accidental'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When it comes to key signatures, the accidentals given apply to ALL of those notes, no matter the register. Thus ALL Bs will become B-flats with the given key signature, and so you don't need to add in that accidental.

(Interestingly, this is not true of lone accidentals! They only apply to *that particular* pitch in *that particular* register.)

And one last bit. You said:

> I have learnt that you either use key signatures or accidentals when writing out a scale. Not both.

Later on, you'll learn that sometimes you'll need key signatures *and* accidentals. So just know that that's possible in the future!

Comment: Wish there was a term for the # and b *in* the key sig. 'cos they're hardly accidentals, are they?

Comment: @Tim I'd say they are just "sharp symbols" and "flat symbols". I agree that "accidentals in the key signature" doesn't make much sense, because "accidental" refers to it being *outside* the key signature.

Comment: Also worth noting: Accidentals within a measure apply to all notes of that pitch in that measure, unless explicitly canceled out by another accidental or the natural. (Is that what was meant by your parenthetical?)

Comment: In parentheses, I meant that accidentals only apply to that *pitch*, not to that *pitch class*, but I was weary of using that terminology.